# Javascript code not functioning with PHP when echo'ed

Tags: javascript, php, html, shopping-cart

I have this code in my shopping cart page where I display the items from session variables.

```
             <?php 
    if(empty(!$_SESSION['name'])){
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $price = $_SESSION['price']; 
        $qty = $_SESSION['qty'];
        $pic = $_SESSION['pic'];
       
        for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
            echo '<div class="row list pt-2 pb-2" id="Mango">
            <img src="'.$pic[$i].'" class="product-image col-4 ">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col align-self-left ml-2 font-weight-bold" id="name0">'.$name[$i].'</div>
                    <div class="col align-self-right ml-2 font-weight-bold " id="eachTag0"> $ <var id="each0">'.$price[$i].'</var> ea.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-1 mb-2 border-top">
                    <div class="col-sm-6  pt-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col ml-4"><a class="btn btn-outline-info " id="Substracting0"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></div>
                            <div class="col input-group" ><input type="text" class="form-control QTY" id="Quantity0" value="'.$qty[$i].'"></div>
                            <div class="col "> <a class="btn btn-outline-info " id="Adding0"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6  pt-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-7 text-center pt-1" style="font-size:19px" id="totTag0"> $ <var  id="tot0"></var></div>
                            <div class="col ml-2"><a class="btn btn-outline-info" id="Deleting0"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> </a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
    }
    else {
        echo "<h2 class='text-center'>Empty cart</h2>";
    }
```

However, I also have javascript code further down this php file which are connected to parts of this code above in the 'echo' by their html ids.

For some reason the javascript code isn't functioning at all. Could it be because this code is 'echoed' by PHP?

JS further down:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            CartStorage = window.localStorage;
            function cartItem  (name, unit, itemprice, quantity, picturepath){
                return {
                    name: name,
                    unit: unit, // " ea." or "/lb"
                    itemprice: itemprice,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    total: function(){ return this.itemprice*this.quantity;},
                    picturepath: picturepath,
                }
            }
            let cartList = [];
            cartList[0] = cartItem("Mango", "ea.", 1.99, 0, "Pictures/Mango-2.jpg" );
            cartList[1] = cartItem("Apple", "/lb", 2.00, 0, "Pictures/appl3.jpg");
            cartList[2] = cartItem("Peach", "ea.", 1.40, 0, "Pictures/peach2.jpg");

            //LOADING PREEXISTING VALUES
            function checkvalues() {
                if (!isNaN(CartStorage.getItem("nbrItems"))) {
                    for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                        let IDstring = "Quantity"+i;
                        document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = CartStorage.getItem(IDstring);
                        cartList[i].quantity=Number(CartStorage.getItem(IDstring));
                        calSingleTotal(cartList[i].name);
                    }
                    calnbrItems();
                    calpretotal()
                    calQST();
                    calGST();
                    calTotal();
                }
            }

            checkvalues();
            document.getElementById("Adding0").addEventListener('click',()=> addplus("Mango"));
            document.getElementById("Substracting0").addEventListener('click',()=>  subminus("Mango"));
            document.getElementById("Deleting0").addEventListener('click', ()=> deletefruit("Mango"));
            document.getElementById("Adding1").addEventListener('click',()=> addplus("Apple"));
            document.getElementById("Substracting1").addEventListener('click',()=>  subminus("Apple"));
            document.getElementById("Deleting1").addEventListener('click', ()=> deletefruit("Apple"));
            document.getElementById("Adding2").addEventListener('click',()=> addplus("Peach"));
            document.getElementById("Substracting2").addEventListener('click',()=>  subminus("Peach"));
            document.getElementById("Deleting2").addEventListener('click', ()=> deletefruit("Peach"));

            function savingQTYArray(){
                for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                    let IDstring = "Quantity"+i;
                    CartStorage.setItem(IDstring, document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder);
                }
            }
            function calpretotal(){
                let pretotal1=0;
                for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                    pretotal1 +=cartList[i].total();
                }
                if(pretotal1.toString().length>3){
                    pretotal1 = Number(pretotal1.toFixed(3));
                }
                document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent = pretotal1;
            }
            function calnbrItems() {
                nbrItems=0;
                for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                    nbrItems += cartList[i].quantity;
                }
                document.getElementById("nbrItems").textContent = nbrItems;
                CartStorage.setItem("nbrItems", nbrItems);
                return nbrItems;
            }
            function calGST(){
                let pretotal1 = Number(document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent);
                let gst1 = pretotal1*0.05;
                if(gst1.toString().length>3){
                    gst1 = Number(gst1.toFixed(2));
                }
                document.getElementById("GST").textContent = gst1;
            }
            function calQST(){
                let pretotal1 = Number(document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent);
                let qst1 = pretotal1*0.09975;
                if(qst1.toString().length>3){
                    qst1 = Number(qst1.toFixed(2));
                }
                document.getElementById("QST").textContent = qst1;
            }
            function calTotal(){
                let pretotal1 = Number(document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent);
                let gst1 = Number(document.getElementById("GST").textContent);
                let qst1 = Number(document.getElementById("QST").textContent);
                let total1 = pretotal1+gst1+qst1;
                if(total1.toString().length>3){
                    total1 = Number(total1.toFixed(2));
                }
                document.getElementById("TOTAL").textContent = total1;
            }
            function addplus(fruitx) {
                let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
                cartList[index].quantity++;
                let IDstring = "Quantity"+index;
                document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = cartList[index].quantity;
                CartStorage.setItem(IDstring, cartList[index].quantity.toString());
                calnbrItems();
                calpretotal();
                calSingleTotal(fruitx);
                calGST();
                calQST();
                calTotal();
            }
            function subminus(fruitx) {
                let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
                if (cartList[index].quantity!=0) {
                    cartList[index].quantity--;
                    let IDstring = "Quantity" + index;
                    document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = cartList[index].quantity;
                    CartStorage.setItem(IDstring, cartList[index].quantity.toString());
                    calnbrItems();
                    calpretotal();
                    calSingleTotal(fruitx);
                    calGST();
                    calQST();
                    calTotal();
                }
            }
            function calSingleTotal(fruitx){
                let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
                let IDstring = "tot"+index;
                let temp = cartList[index].total();
                if(temp.toString().length>3){
                    temp = Number(temp.toFixed(3));
                }
                document.getElementById(IDstring).textContent = temp;
            }
            function deletefruit(fruitx){
                let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
                cartList[index].quantity=0;
                let IDstring = "Quantity" + index;
                document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = "0";
                document.getElementById(cartList[index].name).style.display="none";
                CartStorage.setItem(IDstring,"0");
                calnbrItems();
                calpretotal();
                calSingleTotal(fruitx);
                calGST();
                calQST();
                calTotal();
            }


        </script>
```

Comment: Did you enclose the javascript in <script></script> tags? While echoing them?

Comment: You don't echo javascript-code, you write HTML-code. But this HTML should function if the condition in if-statement is true.

Comment: You also do seem to create multiple rows with the id "Mango". You probably want unique ids. Also please show us the js code that is further down

Comment: _"For some reason the javascript code isn't functioning at all."_ - Then you need to show us the code that doesn't work, together with an explanation what should happen and what actually happens. _"Could it be because this code is 'echoed' by PHP?"_ - No. The PHP code is executed on the server, the result (the output) are then sent to the client, which executes the javascript. Javascript or the client doesn't know, or care, how the HTML was generated on the server.

Comment: Very hard to provide an answer on Javascript when that is the missing piece of the puzzle here.  It could be because it is echoed by PHP but no way to tell without seeing the code as it should be.. As already stated though - ID attributes should be unique

Comment: Sorry guys... Didn't include the JS script as it was quite long, was wishful thinking that the problem might've been obvious by the php code alone. I included it now.

Comment: In the javascript you are using certain IDs ( `document.getElementById("Adding0")` etc ) and these are reflected in the PHP/HTML. These are written to the document in a `for` loop - this suggests there will be duplicate IDs in the DOM. Can you confirm whether or not this is the case please?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes it seems so, these duplicate ids is something I shall fix

Comment: It might be. I would make separate js file and have it loaded after the php.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you're doing wrong is you're calling functions that are not yet declared in your javascript. Your function `checkvalues()` makes calls to functions you have declared later in JavaScript. Move all of your function declarations above that code, like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function cartItem  (name, unit, itemprice, quantity, picturepath){
            return {
                name: name,
                unit: unit, // " ea." or "/lb"
                itemprice: itemprice,
                quantity: quantity,
                total: function(){ return this.itemprice*this.quantity;},
                picturepath: picturepath,
            }
        }
         function checkvalues() {
            if (!isNaN(CartStorage.getItem("nbrItems"))) {
                for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                    let IDstring = "Quantity"+i;
                    document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = CartStorage.getItem(IDstring);
                    cartList[i].quantity=Number(CartStorage.getItem(IDstring));
                    calSingleTotal(cartList[i].name);
                }
                calnbrItems();
                calpretotal()
                calQST();
                calGST();
                calTotal();
            }
        }

        function savingQTYArray(){
            for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                let IDstring = "Quantity"+i;
                CartStorage.setItem(IDstring, document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder);
            }
        }
        function calpretotal(){
            let pretotal1=0;
            for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                pretotal1 +=cartList[i].total();
            }
            if(pretotal1.toString().length>3){
                pretotal1 = Number(pretotal1.toFixed(3));
            }
            document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent = pretotal1;
        }
        function calnbrItems() {
            nbrItems=0;
            for (i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
                nbrItems += cartList[i].quantity;
            }
            document.getElementById("nbrItems").textContent = nbrItems;
            CartStorage.setItem("nbrItems", nbrItems);
            return nbrItems;
        }
        function calGST(){
            let pretotal1 = Number(document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent);
            let gst1 = pretotal1*0.05;
            if(gst1.toString().length>3){
                gst1 = Number(gst1.toFixed(2));
            }
            document.getElementById("GST").textContent = gst1;
        }
        function calQST(){
            let pretotal1 = Number(document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent);
            let qst1 = pretotal1*0.09975;
            if(qst1.toString().length>3){
                qst1 = Number(qst1.toFixed(2));
            }
            document.getElementById("QST").textContent = qst1;
        }
        function calTotal(){
            let pretotal1 = Number(document.getElementById("pretotal").textContent);
            let gst1 = Number(document.getElementById("GST").textContent);
            let qst1 = Number(document.getElementById("QST").textContent);
            let total1 = pretotal1+gst1+qst1;
            if(total1.toString().length>3){
                total1 = Number(total1.toFixed(2));
            }
            document.getElementById("TOTAL").textContent = total1;
        }
        function addplus(fruitx) {
            let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
            cartList[index].quantity++;
            let IDstring = "Quantity"+index;
            document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = cartList[index].quantity;
            CartStorage.setItem(IDstring, cartList[index].quantity.toString());
            calnbrItems();
            calpretotal();
            calSingleTotal(fruitx);
            calGST();
            calQST();
            calTotal();
        }
        function subminus(fruitx) {
            let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
            if (cartList[index].quantity!=0) {
                cartList[index].quantity--;
                let IDstring = "Quantity" + index;
                document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = cartList[index].quantity;
                CartStorage.setItem(IDstring, cartList[index].quantity.toString());
                calnbrItems();
                calpretotal();
                calSingleTotal(fruitx);
                calGST();
                calQST();
                calTotal();
            }
        }
        function calSingleTotal(fruitx){
            let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
            let IDstring = "tot"+index;
            let temp = cartList[index].total();
            if(temp.toString().length>3){
                temp = Number(temp.toFixed(3));
            }
            document.getElementById(IDstring).textContent = temp;
        }
        function deletefruit(fruitx){
            let index = cartList.findIndex(cartList => cartList.name === fruitx);
            cartList[index].quantity=0;
            let IDstring = "Quantity" + index;
            document.getElementById(IDstring).placeholder = "0";
            document.getElementById(cartList[index].name).style.display="none";
            CartStorage.setItem(IDstring,"0");
            calnbrItems();
            calpretotal();
            calSingleTotal(fruitx);
            calGST();
            calQST();
            calTotal();
        }


        CartStorage = window.localStorage;
        
        let cartList = [];
        cartList[0] = cartItem("Mango", "ea.", 1.99, 0, "Pictures/Mango-2.jpg" );
        cartList[1] = cartItem("Apple", "/lb", 2.00, 0, "Pictures/appl3.jpg");
        cartList[2] = cartItem("Peach", "ea.", 1.40, 0, "Pictures/peach2.jpg");

        //LOADING PREEXISTING VALUES
        checkvalues();
        document.getElementById("Adding0").addEventListener('click',()=> addplus("Mango"));
        document.getElementById("Substracting0").addEventListener('click',()=>  subminus("Mango"));
        document.getElementById("Deleting0").addEventListener('click', ()=> deletefruit("Mango"));
        document.getElementById("Adding1").addEventListener('click',()=> addplus("Apple"));
        document.getElementById("Substracting1").addEventListener('click',()=>  subminus("Apple"));
        document.getElementById("Deleting1").addEventListener('click', ()=> deletefruit("Apple"));
        document.getElementById("Adding2").addEventListener('click',()=> addplus("Peach"));
        document.getElementById("Substracting2").addEventListener('click',()=>  subminus("Peach"));
        document.getElementById("Deleting2").addEventListener('click', ()=> deletefruit("Peach"));
    </script>
```

I can't see your HTML, but you'll also want to make sure those final `document.getElementById` calls are being made after they have been added to the DOM.

This probably goes without saying, but also make sure that you are using a browser that can parse ES6. Either that or you might just want to change the syntax for your event listeners to legacy format (I'd do that anyway since we're not talking about a whole lot of code or benefit from using ES6 in this one area).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried putting the script before the php code but it didn't work. Also, I thought that php is rendered before JS?

Comment: Well, that depends, but it's a separate issue. The very javascript code you had before was calling javascript functions declared later in the script.

Comment: Have you checked your console for javascript errors? What about modifying some of those event listeners so they have a `console.log` to verify that they are getting added to the elements you want?